# MySQL Workbench ошибка "Could not accuire management acces for administration"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Когда нажимаю что-то из вкладки Server в воркбенче вылезает подобная ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать отмена, то появляется ещё это окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кто-нибудь, помогите, в интернете я только пару чуваков нашел с такой ошибкой и ни одного решения... Я что не достоин изучения MySQL? За что мне такое наказание

Comment: Значит вам надо учиться гуглить. Там прямым текстом ошибка написана

Comment: Прошу, я гуглил, молил бога, я смотрел индусов. Но все равного решения не нашёл. В самой ошибке написано типа "проверьте переменную system32 в path". Я проверил, её там не было. Добавил, перезагрузил. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Покажите как вы её добавили

Comment: Поиск - Изменение системных переменных среды - Переменные среды - Path - Изменить. Потом Создать - И прописал "C:\Windows\System32"

Comment: та же история!!! дичь какая то. как исправить то??